# How was the explosives scene shot?

Tags: film-techniques, four-lions

In this picture, it can be seen that *Faisal* (role in this movie) is running towards the sheep.

[image]

Here, he got killed by explosives.

[image]

It was a continuous shot with **no cuts**;  I wonder how this scene is done.

Comment: Looks to me as though the stuntman took a dive into a pit behind where the explosives were placed. At least that's all I can think of from looking at the video on YouTube.

Comment: If you look carefully at the scene, you can see a color change immediately after he falls, and surrounding where he falls and the berm behind him. IMO this is a clone-tool edit. The explosion itself is CGI. The sheep are running already and they show no reaction (such as Super Turbo Boost) when the explosion appears. Don't be fooled by the "sheep killed" in the credits, this is a satire/parody. (the grass is a ready-made green screen).